# CI/CD script for build & deploy docker image in aws EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, gitlab, cicd

can I build ,push(to gitlab registry) and deploy the image (to aws EC2) using this CI/CD configuration?

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  # Use the official docker image.

  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  # Default branch leaves tag empty (= latest tag)
  # All other branches are tagged with the escaped branch name (commit ref slug)
  script:
    - |
      if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" ]]; then
        tag=""
        echo "Running on default branch '$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH': tag = 'latest'"
      else
        tag=":$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
        echo "Running on branch '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH': tag = $tag"
      fi
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}"
  # Run this job in a branch where a Dockerfile exists

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@18.0.0.82 "sudo docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY; sudo docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}; cd /home/crud_app; sudo docker-compose up -d"
  after_script:
    - sudo docker logout

  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      exists:
        - Dockerfile
```

after the script build is getting suceed, deploy gets fail.

(build suceeded)
[image: Build CI got suceeded]

(deploy got failed)
[image: deploy got failed]

the configuration must be build and deploy the image

Comment: that line make an error  : echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -

Comment: Regarding the last error, in the "after script", It says that `sudo` is not found.
Did you try removing it from `sudo docker logout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors, but the overall Pipeline seems good.

1. You cannot use `ssh-add` without having the agent running
2. Why you create the .ssh folder manually if afterwards you're explicitly ignoring the key that is going to be stored under `known_hosts`?
3. Using `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` is dangerous and totally unrecommended.

On the `before_script` add the following:

```
before_script:
    - eval `ssh-agent`
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan -H 18.0.0.82 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Also, don't use `sudo` on your `ubuntu` user, better add it to the `docker` group or connect through SSH to an user that is in the `docker` group.

---

In case you don't have already a `docker` group in your EC2 instance, now it's a good moment to configure it:

Access to your EC2 instance and create the `docker` group:

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
```

Add the `ubuntu` user to the `docker` group:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker ubuntu
```

---

Now change your `script` to:

```
script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD > docker_password
    - scp docker_password ubuntu@18.0.0.82:~/tmp/docker_password
    - ssh ubuntu@18.0.0.82 "cat ~/tmp/docker_password | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY; docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}; cd /home/crud_app; docker-compose up -d; docker logout; rm -f ~/tmp/docker_password"
```

Also, remember that in the `after_script` you aren't in the EC2 instance but within the runner image so you don't need to `logout`, but it would be good to kill the SSH agent tho.

**Final Job**

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - eval `ssh-agent`
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan -H 18.0.0.82 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD > docker_password
    - scp docker_password ubuntu@18.0.0.82:~/tmp/docker_password
    - ssh ubuntu@18.0.0.82 "cat ~/tmp/docker_password | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY; docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}; cd /home/crud_app; docker-compose up -d; docker logout; rm -f ~/tmp/docker_password"
  after_script:
    - kill $SSH_AGENT_PID
    - rm docker_password
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      exists:
        - Dockerfile
```

Comment: please explain this script  I didn't get what's happenning in here          "- scp docker_password ubuntu@18.0.0.82:~/tmp/docker_password"

Comment: You were trying to pass the password in the login through the `stdin` but there wasn't anything writing on the standard input. So I wrote the password in the file `docker_password` and then I copied it to the EC2 instance with `scp`. Then on login, I read the content of that file with `cat` and the output is piped to the `docker login` command.